# How to kill all asynchronous processes

Tags: bash, process, asynchronous, command, kill

Suppose we have a BASH script running some commands in the background. At some time we want to kill all of them, whether they have finished their job or not.

Here's an example:

```
function command_doing_nothing () {
  sleep 10
  echo "I'm done"
}

for (( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )); do
  command_doing_nothing &
done

echo "Jobs:"
jobs

sleep 1

# Now we want to kill them
```

How to kill those 3 jobs running in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To kill **ALL** jobs (as long as this script is running in its own shell instance):

```
for x in $(jobs -p); do kill $x; done
```

Comment: Please don't do `kill -9` when it's unnecessary. http://speculation.org/garrick/kill-9.html